# PHP Session's not detectable after refresh

Tags: php, session

I'm devolping an application in PHP where I need to use sessions.
I've developed my application with a three layer architecture.

I use only one PHP page and dummy forms to submit user actions and all the processing is being made throught entities/function specific classes.

When the page is first opened I check the variables, if it was never opened earlier I present the login form.

When I receive the post from this form I check the user and if the user is ok I start the session

```
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    if($_POST['login']=='login')
    {
        //valida user
        $accoes=$du->login($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
        if($accoes===false)
        {
            echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\"JavaScript\" TYPE=\"text/javascript\">";
            echo "alert('Erro no Login');";
            echo "</SCRIPT>";
            unset($accoes);
        }
        else
        {
            //utilizador valido
            echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\"JavaScript\" TYPE=\"text/javascript\">";
            echo "alert('Utilizador válido');";
            echo "</SCRIPT>";
            session_start();
            $user="teste";
            $screen="logged";
            $_SESSION['user']=$user;
        }
    }
}
```

Although when this page is refreshed via a user action I can't see the session id nor the session variables.

Am I missing something like session_commit or other instruction?

Should session_start() also appear before trying to chech session variables?

Could it be something missing in PHP.ini file?

When I reload the first thing I do is the check for session variables

```
if(session_id() != '') {
    $user=$_SESSION['user'];
}
```

I know I should know how to resolve this, but til now my experience with PHP was throw Flex/Flash so session management wasn't really necessary.

Thanks for the help

Comment: did you called session_start() at top for each page?

Comment: *Should session_start() also appear before trying to chech session variables?* Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing that I can surely point out .. your session_start() should be the first line after opening php tahg

```
<?php
   session_start();
```

And it should be called on every page where `$_SESSION` is to be called ..
otherwise session will not be properly accessible

Comment: I used it only when the user has succesfuly logged in because in POO vision it seemed more logic! But when it failed I begin to think it could be it! But I needed to be sure! Thanks!

Comment: However I want to use only one page, and change its contents acording to the processing made by the layers below! Even so between calls I need to maintain session control! If I use session_start() on the top, how I should pass the session ID? Via Post? Its done automatically? LOL! So stupid! It's done via clients IP and browser! The session can exist even before login! It's all done by the vairables I put in it! I'm tired of knowing it, but I lack the experience!

Comment: You are right .. when you start the session the you need not to worry about the transfer of the sessionId ... when you need to check whether user is login or not .. do no check about `session_id()` instead check about user specific parameter like `$_SESSION['user']` which uniquely identifies the user ..